# Why do keyframed objects cause fluid baking to slow down so much?

Tags: fluid-simulation, baking

In the following figures we show the results of our attempts in order to mix a *key-framed animation* with a *fluid simulation*. As you can see, in the top one the obstacle is *static* (*fix*) but in the bottom one it turns counterclockwise slowly.

The *Static* one took only **`5`** minutes to be baked, however, the *dynamic* one took **`65`** minutes on the same computer system!?

We need to know:
*1. First, whether this massive time difference is usual even though there is no significant difference between the two simulation?

2. Is there any tip / trick to speed-up the baking of mixed animation/simulations?*

Our final simulation (*for education purpose, btw*) will be much more complex in terms of dynamic and the number of objects in it.

[image: static object]

[image: dynamic object]

Comment: Did you enable *Export Animated Mesh*?

Comment: @gandalf3 No we didn't. Should we? For the two simulation everything is exactly the same except in the `dynamic one` we have used key-frames to rotate the obstacle.

Comment: @Developer Not need do it. Thats is for calculate animations with parents, objects with armatures and so on.

Comment: @Developer I was wondering because enabling it will drastically slow down the simulation, so I thought it was a possible cause.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes. The liquid system must translate one moving object to the domain matrix, making it process for every frame, and calculate the new differences and forces produced by the push of the object over the liquid. Of course, this requires more time. 
   I guess if the obstacle is really complex (more faces), this also requires more time.
2. If you can use lower resolution, less to time to bake. Use lower resolution for tests and increase the resolution for the final product. Take a look at [my answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6563/599) on your other question.