# Is there a way to delete specific parts of a baked fluid simulation?

Tags: selection-tools, fluid-simulation, baking

I'm working on a fluid simulation right now. At some places the fluid is seen through the obstacles. Is there a way to select those "false fluids" and remove them?

Comment: It should help increasing resolution of the fluid simulation in the Domain's settings - https://www.blender.org/manual/physics/fluid/domain.html#options. You could also add subsurf to the Domain object to smooth baked simulation. Take a look at this (probably) related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6561/how-to-avoid-fluid-appearing-outside-collision-objects

Comment: Boolean modifier?